# Highlight SVG area when an option is selected in drop down list

Tags: svg, dropdown, highlight

can I ask if how can I achieve this. I want to highlight an area in SVG when a particular option in drop down list is selected. My SVG is a school vicinity map and the options in the drop down list are the areas in the school.
Please help me. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an example of how you could do it:

```js
var dropDown = document.getElementById('area-dropdown');
var highlightAreas = document.getElementsByClassName('area');

dropDown.addEventListener('change', function() {
    // Remove existing highlights
    for (var i = 0; i < highlightAreas.length; i++) {
        highlightAreas[i].classList.remove('highlight');
    }

    // Get path associated with selected area and
    var selectedArea = document.getElementById('area-' + this.value);
    selectedArea.classList.add('highlight');
});
```

```css
.area {
    stroke: black;
    stroke-width: 1;
    fill: #b8b8b8;
}

.highlight {
    fill: #ec008c;
}
```

```html
<form>
    <label>Areas</label>
    <select id="area-dropdown">
        <option selected="selected" disabled="disabled">Select an area</option>
        <option value="a">Area A</option>
        <option value="b">Area B</option>
        <option value="c">Area C</option>
    </select>
</form>

<div style="margin-top:10px">
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="300" height="200" viewBox="0 0 300 200" id="areas-svg">
        <rect id="background" width="300" height="200" fill="#e8e8e8"/>
        <path class="area" id="area-a" d="M20 20H280V80H120V180H20z"/>
        <path class="area" id="area-b" d="M120 80V180H200V80z"/>
        <path class="area" id="area-c" d="M220 100H280V160H220z"/>
    </svg>
</div>
```

It works by adding a class to the selected area which causes it to have a different fill. You could instead change the visibility of the paths used to highlight areas.

EDIT: Here's a version with markers:

```js
var dropDown = document.getElementById('area-dropdown');
var highlightAreas = document.getElementsByClassName('marker');

dropDown.addEventListener('change', function() {
    // Remove existing highlights
    for (var i = 0; i < highlightAreas.length; i++) {
        highlightAreas[i].setAttributeNS(null, 'visibility', 'hidden');
    }

    // Get path associated with selected area and
    var selectedArea = document.getElementById('area-' + this.value);
    selectedArea.setAttributeNS(null, 'visibility', 'visible');;
});
```

```css
.area {
    stroke: black;
    stroke-width: 1;
    fill: #b8b8b8;
}
.highlight {
    fill: #ec008c;
}
text {
    text-anchor: middle;
    dominant-baseline: central;
}
```

```html
<form>
    <label>Areas</label>
    <select id="area-dropdown">
        <option selected="selected" disabled="disabled">Select an area</option>
        <option value="a">Area A</option>
        <option value="b">Area B</option>
        <option value="c">Area C</option>
    </select>
</form>

<div style="margin-top:10px">
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="300" height="200" viewBox="0 0 300 200" id="areas-svg">
        <rect id="background" width="300" height="200" fill="#e8e8e8"/>
        <path class="area" d="M20 20H280V80H120V180H20z"/>
        <path class="area" d="M120 80V180H200V80z"/>
        <path class="area" d="M220 100H280V160H220z"/>
        <g class="marker" visibility="hidden" id="area-a">
            <circle class="highlight" cx="70" cy="80" r="12"/>
            <text x="70" y="80">A</text>
        <g>
        <g class="marker" visibility="hidden" id="area-b">
            <circle class="highlight" cx="160" cy="130" r="12"/>
            <text x="160" y="130">B</text>
        <g>
        <g class="marker" visibility="hidden" id="area-c">
            <circle class="highlight" cx="250" cy="130" r="12"/>
            <text x="250" y="130">C</text>
        <g>
    </svg>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks sir. Can I ask if how can I put a marker on the svg area when it is selected in the drop down list?

Comment: I think the `symbol` might be appropriate for this scenario.

Comment: @AlvinYanson No problem. If my answer solved your problem, can you accept it, thanks!

Comment: Ignore my previous comment. Is there a way @PeterCollingridge to add animation to the marker when it is selected in the drop down list? Thanks again

Comment: @AlvinYanson you can ask that as a new question.